# Which PDB need be assigned to system pods for cluster auto scaler?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

Playing with cluster autoscaler I've noticed that scale-down is not working due to standard k8s pods:

```
Fast evaluation: node aks-nodepool1-37748512-0 cannot be removed: non-daemonset, non-mirrored, non-pdb-assignedkube-system pod present: kube-dns-v20-8748686c5-27psn
```

What is a proper PodDisruptionBudget for kube-dns and are there any best practices for standard system POD PDBs? Why aren't they configured by default?

Answer (score 2):

Inside Kubernetes docs about [Disruptions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/) we can read:

> An Application Owner can create a `PodDisruptionBudget` object (PDB) for each application. A PDB limits the number pods of a replicated application that are down simultaneously from voluntary disruptions. For example, a quorum-based application would like to ensure that the number of replicas running is never brought below the number needed for a quorum. A web front end might want to ensure that the number of replicas serving load never falls below a certain percentage of the total.

You can see examples on how to correctly enable, tune and disable `PodDisruptionBudget` for kube-dns inside Kubernetes docs for [Autoscale the DNS Service in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-horizontal-autoscaling/).

Also Marton Sereg wrote a good article about [Draining Kubernetes nodes](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/drain/), in which he explains how does draining works and what's happening inside the cluster.

As for configuration defaults I was able to find this discussion [Reasonable defaults with eviction and PodDisruptionBudget #35318](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/35318).

Comment: While I appreciate the answer I must say that even after working through the links I still did not find any hints on default values for system pods.

Comment: why is it so hard to find a straight answer to this question, the closest thing i've found is this https://gist.github.com/kenthua/fc06c6ea52a25a51bc07e70c8f781f8f

Comment: and now that link is gone!